# Why is the shadow of a wind turbine a bit slow at first then very quickly, etc. and not equivalent to the wings?

Tags: visible-light, everyday-life, shadow

When I stand at a wind turbine and look at the shadow on the ground, the shadow is a bit slow at first then very quickly, etc. Very strange.

Comment: I think you're going to need to link to a video of this phenomenon.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Depending on the angle of the sun, the shadow becomes elongated so that it traces out an ellipse rather than a circle. This means that the shadows of the blades must traverse a different distance across the ground but within the same time period, thus giving rise to the periodic variation in velocity.

If the sun is at an angle $\alpha$ in the sky (see the diagram below) then there are four intervals of interest:

- $\alpha<\frac{\pi}{4}$: the sun is low in the sky and the shadow is longer than the actual turbine. As a result, the shadow must occasionally speed up.
- $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{4}$: the dimensions of the turbine are preserved and the shadow moves at a constant speed.
- $\alpha>\frac{\pi}{4}$: the sun is high in the sky and the shadow is shorter. It must therefore occasionally slow down.
- $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{2}$: the sun is directly overhead and no shadow is cast (at least, the blades cannot be distinguished).

---

[image]

---

This is simple to tackle mathematically. When the sun is directly behind/in front of the turbine, the coordinates of a particular blade are transformed as follows when projected onto the ground:

$$ R(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))\mapsto R(\cos(\theta)/\tan(\alpha),\sin(\theta)) $$

as is shown above. The elongation is even greater when the sun is at a horizontal angle with respect to the normal of the blades, but I shall ignore this effect for simplicity.

While the velocity of an actual blade ($R\dot{\theta}$) is constant, its projection has a velocity that depends on the angle $\theta$,

$$ v=R\dot{\theta}\sqrt{\frac{\sin^2(\theta)}{\tan^2(\alpha)}+\cos^2(\theta)} $$

and so it follows that the shadow speed varies.

For example, here is a plot of the relative tangential velocity of the shadow as a function of $\theta$ when the sun is relatively low in the sky ($\alpha=\pi/6$):

[image]

Comment: +1 Nicely done. Maybe a bit more populist intro may help but a useful answer.

Comment: So, there are 4 interesting situations, of the sun at his angle?  1) When the sun is at an angle < 45 degrees?   2) at exactly 45 ° ?   3) If the sun is higher than 45 °? you get an ellipse again ?   4) In the limit, when the sun is at an altitude of 90 ° ? what here?

Comment: @YCV I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Lemon: A brilliant masterpiece! If you don't mind, can you tell me how you made this?

Comment: @user36790 I use [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) for schematics.

Comment: +1 to this mind-blowing answer and of course the masterpiece!